# Is it possible to replicate vim-unimpaired [p paste behaviour?

Tags: evil

Evil-unimpaired (https://github.com/zmaas/evil-unimpaired/) tries to replicate vim-unimpaired, but the paste behaviour is just a dumbed down version of the original.
The evil-unimpaired behaviour on [p:

```
(defun evil-unimpaired-paste-below ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-insert-newline-below)
  (evil-paste-after 1 evil-this-register))
```

It just inserts a newline and then pastes the register content. It doesn't care whether register content has a newline or not. It just inserts a new line anyway. Let's say I have the following text and I copy the second line with `yy`:

```
first line
   |second line
```

When I paste with `[p` it becomes

```
first line
    second line
    
   |second line
```

which is not a desirable output. Compare it to vim-unimpaired behaviour:

```
first line
   |second line
```

Paste with `[p`

```
first line
    second line
   |second line
```

The same problem applies to ]p which is supposed to paste text above current line. I want to know if there is a existing solution or can someone show me how to update the evil-unimpaired function so it works properly. My emacs-fu is pretty much nonexistent, unfortunately

Comment: I don't think the question is very clear at this point. Please edit it to clarify what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @TerryTsao updated

Answer (score 0):

The following satisfies your requirements I believe.
I had the same problem, and I've used the following to get behavior like in Vim.

```
(defun +ani/evil-unimpaired-paste-above ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((register (if evil-this-register
                      evil-this-register
                    ?\")))
    (when (not (member 'evil-yank-line-handler (get-text-property 0 'yank-handler (evil-get-register register))))
      (evil-insert-newline-above))
    (evil-paste-before 1 register)))

(defun +ani/evil-unimpaired-paste-below ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((register (if evil-this-register
                      evil-this-register
                    ?\")))
    (when (not (member 'evil-yank-line-handler (get-text-property 0 'yank-handler (evil-get-register register))))
      (evil-insert-newline-below))
    (evil-paste-after 1 register)))
```

Credits goes to `anihm136` on GitHub where I took this code from:

https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/5422#issuecomment-939250010

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please delete this answer, or summarize the info for it that's at that link.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the heads up! Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks..........